# Can an electron transit within the same $n$-level?

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals

Under selection rules for multi-electron atoms in LS coupling, its generally written that there is no restriction on the total quantum number $n$. Does it mean that an electron transit within the same $n$ level, i.e., can $\Delta n =0$?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know when you derive the transition rules for some interaction with some interaction hamiltonian $H_{int}$ you investigate the matrix element $\langle f | H_{int} |i\rangle$ between some initial $|i\rangle$ and final $|f\rangle$ state labeles by the appropriate quantum numbers. The allowed transitions are given by the non-zero matrix elements, which constrains the relation between the quantum numbers between the initial and final state. The transition rules are usually formulated as only the constraints, so if it doesn't say anything about $\Delta n$ for example it should not matter. To see a list of transitions in multi electron atoms [here](https://www.nist.gov/system/files/documents/srd/jpcrd382009565p.pdf).

It might be useful to look at the derivation of the selection rules once again to properly understand the meaning of them.

Comment: Well, sorry for a late reply, but I want to discuss further about this. There was a question I was solving in which I've to find the number of allowed transitions in the fine-spectra of H-alpha lines. The answer was 7. Refer here for an image I found online - https://d3i71xaburhd42.cloudfront.net/c06426415b17ea409d2784bb36383b009bce6d38/3-Figure1-1.png . So, this was only possible answer if the transitions were not allowed within the same n level, i.e., I can't transit an electron in the fine structures within same n.